Python : Record 5 RTSP to 5 video files (with Thread) but get only the last frame
I'm trying to record 5 RTSP streams (from IP Cameras) to 5 video files in one python script with threading on a Windows machine.
But with my code, I only have the last frame of each stream in my video files.
So, my MyVideoFile.mp4 contain only one unique frame who look like the last one recorded.
Where am I wrong ?
What need I to do ?
PS : sorry for my poor english...
my code :
from threading import Thread
import cv2
import os
import time

class RTSPVideoWriterObject(object):
    def __init__(self, src, camname, folder):
        # Create a VideoCapture object
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
        self.camname = camname
        self.folder = folder

        # Default resolutions of the frame are obtained (system dependent)
        self.frame_width = int(self.capture.get(3))
        self.frame_height = int(self.capture.get(4))
        self.fps = int(self.capture.get(5))
        
        # Set up name and folder
        folder = str(time.strftime(os.path.join(self.folder,'%Y_%m_%d/%Hh')))
        if not os.path.exists(folder):
            os.makedirs(folder)
        filename = folder + '/' + str(time.strftime(self.camname+' %Y_%m_%d - %Hh%M')) + '.mp4'
        # Set up codec and output video settings
        self.codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'avc1')
        self.output_video = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, self.codec, self.fps, (self.frame_width, self.frame_height))
        
        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                self.status, self.frame = self.capture.read()

    def show_frame(self):
        # Display frames in main program
        if self.status:
            cv2.imshow(self.camname, self.frame)
        
        # Press Q on keyboard to stop recording
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            self.capture.release()
            self.output_video.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            exit(1)

    def record_vid(self):
        # Save obtained frame into video output file
        self.output_video.write(self.frame)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    rtsp_stream_link_1 = "My RTSP link1"
    rtsp_stream_link_2 = "My RTSP link2"
    rtsp_stream_link_3 = "My RTSP link3"
    rtsp_stream_link_4 = "My RTSP link4"
    rtsp_stream_link_5 = "My RTSP link5"

    video_stream_widget_1 = RTSPVideoWriterObject(rtsp_stream_link_1, 'MyFileName1', 'MyFolder1')
    video_stream_widget_2 = RTSPVideoWriterObject(rtsp_stream_link_2, 'MyFileName2', 'MyFolder2')
    video_stream_widget_3 = RTSPVideoWriterObject(rtsp_stream_link_3, 'MyFileName3', 'MyFolder3')
    video_stream_widget_4 = RTSPVideoWriterObject(rtsp_stream_link_4, 'MyFileName4', 'MyFolder4')
    video_stream_widget_5 = RTSPVideoWriterObject(rtsp_stream_link_5, 'MyFileName5', 'MyFolder5')

    video_stream_widget_1.show_frame() # to display one RTSP

    # Record the 5 RTSP to videos files
    video_stream_widget_1.record_vid()
    video_stream_widget_2.record_vid()
    video_stream_widget_3.record_vid()
    video_stream_widget_4.record_vid()
    video_stream_widget_5.record_vid()

Hope someone can help me :)
And again, thanks in advance.

voting to close as typo. this is a beginner's coding mistake. record_vid() is called once (5 times), and it writes one frame each time. all the threading is wasted effort.

please review the [mre] article, also [ask]

sorry to be a beginner....You never were a beginner ? I'm trying to learn and understand Thread and Class. Not so easy without help or school background. But thanks, I will go read more

this site is not a general forum. it has a specific focus: questions that many people could have, so it's worth answering them well and once. your question is only useful to you. this site is certainly not a tutoring service. your question simply doesn't fit the site. you should seek out sites/forums that are tutoring services. perhaps reddit suits you better?

The problem with your approach is that the method RTSPVideoWriterObject.update() which is the target of the thread logic (self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())) is going to run in parallel with your video writing function  RTSPVideoWriterObject.record_vid().  When RTSPVideoWriterObject.record_vid() is called, it is executed exactly ONCE and will only save off the latest frame self.frame that the thread is on.
It is unclear how exactly you intend for this to function (that is how many frames do you want to save) but a event-based approach would probably be helpful here.
As a rough outline consider this revision:
class RTSPVideoWriterObject(object):
  def __init__(self, src, camname, folder):
    # ... Your code here ...
    self.stopRecordEvent = Event()


  def update(self):
    # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
    while not self.stopRecordEvent.is_set():    # Continue until event is called then break out of wile 
        if self.capture.isOpened():
            self.status, self.frame = self.capture.read()
            self.output_video.write(self.frame) #Write each frame as it is collected


  # Call this after N seconds to get (roughly) that length of recording
  def stop_recording(self):
    self.stopRecordEvent.set()

  # Call this after you are doing with the cv2 resources
  def release_resources(self):
    self.caputre.release()
    self.output_video.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

this outline describe creating a threading.Event to let the thread know when to stop execution. Until the event is set, the thread will continue to run saving off frames to the video.
I would recommend being sure to properly close the threads and managing the shared resources in the main function. Using the .join() method is useful as well but I believe this correction above should be sufficient (though not production ready :) ).
Also refer to python's threading and thread event documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html
https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects

the goal is to record in continue (until I kill the script) but to separate videos into one minute videos

the code boils down to calling record_vid five times in the main function, the calls of which save one frame each. that's all you had to say. all the threading is pointless. OP should review the [mre] article because it links to a tutorial that explains debugging.
